# How to randomly generate and test if an integer is unique on a list and repeat if it is not

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a program to learn binary. It would work as follows: the program asks me to convert from decimal to binary between 0 and 15, once this conversion is done the decimal digit is removed and must not reappear in one of the next questions. Thus, the 16 digits will be asked one and only one time in the disorder.

To do this, I randomly generate a number to convert and then check if it has already been used, and therein lies my problem: I am supposed to test in a list if the random number has already appeared and if so, generate a new one until it is unique, except that I don't succeed, even if it already exists the number is accepted and the question is asked instead of generating another one.

```
import random

def conversion(binaire):
    if binaire=="0000":
        decimal="0"
    elif binaire=="0001":
        decimal="1"
    elif binaire=="0010":
        decimal="2"
    elif binaire=="0011":
        decimal="3"
    elif binaire=="0100":
        decimal="4"
    elif binaire=="0101":
        decimal="5"
    elif binaire=="0110":
        decimal="6"
    elif binaire=="0111":
        decimal="7"
    elif binaire=="1000":
        decimal="8"
    elif binaire=="1001":
        decimal="9"
    elif binaire=="1010":
        decimal="10"
    elif binaire=="1011":
        decimal="11"
    elif binaire=="1100":
        decimal="12"
    elif binaire=="1101":
        decimal="13"
    elif binaire=="1110":
        decimal="14"
    elif binaire=="1111":
        decimal="15"
    return decimal
        
    
def existe(liste, n):
    if n in liste:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def apprendre_binaire():
    remain = 15
    binaire = ["0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"]
    binaire_deja_fait = []
    remain = 15
    print("Début du programme d'entrainement\n")
    while remain >=0:
        continuer=1
        number = random.randint(0,15)

#This part is supposed to test if number is unique or not

        while continuer==1 :
            test = existe(binaire_deja_fait, number)
            if test == 1:
                number = random.randint(0,15)
            else:
                continuer = 0
                    
        print("Convertir", number, "en binaire :\n")
        answer = input()
        if answer == binaire[number]:
            print("Juste\n")
        else:
            print("Faux, seconde chance :\n")
            answer = input()
            if answer == binaire[number]:
                print("Juste\n")
            else:
                print("Faux, la bonne réponse était", binaire[number], "\n")
                
        add=conversion(binaire[number])
        binaire_deja_fait.append(add)
        print(binaire_deja_fait)
        remain-=1
    print("Fin du programme d'entrainement")
        
apprendre_binaire()
```

This is a project to help me in my studies, I am aware that it is not optimal.

Comment: I think you meant: `binaire_deja_fait.append(number)`. What you are doing now is adding the string returned by `conversion()` which is never going to be equal to anything returned by `random.randint(0,15)`.  (Why do you need your `conversion()` function?)

Comment: It worked, thank you very much, I spent two hours trying to figure out why it wasn't working without doubting that the problem was here... I did the conversion function because I was adding "answer" to my list and not "number", so it was binary I was comparing to decimal. I don't know why I didn't go straight to number like you, I admit I'm confused about my mistake haha

thanks again! Now I'm going to run it until I know everything by heart :)

Comment: Also your `conversion()` is redundant as there is the built-in `int(x,2)`

Comment: I would use `return True`, `return False` instead of `return 1`, `return 0` - and then you could reduce `existe` to `def existe(liste, n): return str(n) in liste` because `... in ...` also returns `True`/`False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that you are appending strings to `binaire_deja_fait` and asking if it contains integer.

You can fix it by changing `existe` to:

```
def existe(liste, n):
    if str(n) in liste:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

I absolutely hate the existance of the `existe` function, tho. Instead of:

```
    while continuer==1 :
        test = existe(binaire_deja_fait, number)
        if test == 1:
           number = random.randint(0,15)
        else:
           continuer = 0
```

I would do :

```
    while str(number) in binaire_deja_fait:
        number = random.randint(0,15)
```

and removed the existe function.

The other thing is that your program with enter the endless loop once all numbers are exhausted.

Comment: This is clever, ty for the answer !

Comment: Please upvote and accept my question if it is correct.

Comment: I can't upvote  I need at least 15 reputation sorry, but I thank you a lot and when I'll have enough reputation I'll come back to upvote